# disable a button using class in angular js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have several buttons with class `btn-danger`. I need to disable these buttons using a condition.

My controller contains the following code:

```
if($scope.valuess == 1134){
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger").disabled = true;
}
```

But it showing error. Please help me.

I have many pages with same class. So it is not possible to make change on button format. I am looking for a solution in controller page alone..

Comment: Which error you have got?

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection. Try to loop over each element.

Comment: document.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger")[0] is not defined is the error i got.. I have many pages. So it is not possible to change the button structure..

Answer (score 3):

you can use `ng-disabled` to disable the button.

```
<button ng-disabled="checked">Button</button>
```

for more details : [ng-disabled](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled)

```
if($scope.valuess == 1134){
    $scope.checked = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, getElementsByClassName returns an array of elements and you need to iterate over them and set disabled = true individually for each element.

Answer (score 0):

For more information, in angular you don't need to have id or class to handle the elements, you just need a flexible model to cover what between controller and view.

> You can also use conditions in the view directly

```js
var app = angular.module("app", []);


app.controller("ctrl", function($scope){
  var value = 1134;
  $scope.value = 55;
  $scope.disabled = value == 1134 ? true : false;
  $scope.items = [{style:'btn-danger', disable: true},{style:'btn-success', disable: false}]
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <button ng-disabled="disabled">button 1</button>
  <button ng-disabled="value == 55 ? true : false">button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
  
  <hr>
  <h5>forEach</h5>
  <button ng-repeat="item in items" ng-class="item.style" ng-disabled="item.disable">button {{$index}}</button>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it easy, simple add ng-disable connected to a variable in scope.

```
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="myBooleanVariable">Button</button>
```

on your controller define your variable

```
angular.module('controllerAsExample', [])
  .controller('MyController ', ['$scope', function($scope) {
      $scope.myBooleanVariable = true;

  }]);
```

after in your controller 
you can disable or enable the button

```
if($scope.valuess == 1134){
  myBooleanVariable = false
}
```

another fast solution can be
this

```
<button ng-model="button" ng-disabled="values == 1134">Button</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

`HTMLElement.getElementsByClassName()`returns a list even if you have 0 or 1 element fetched. means that `[].disabled` is throwing you the error.

If your aim is to set to all the elements with that class the `disabled`attribute, you can do like this

```
if($scope.valuess == 1134){
    document.getElementsByClassName("btn-danger").forEach((e) => {
        e.setAttribute('disabled', true);
    }
}
```

you can also use the `ng-disabled` directive

```
<button ng-disabled="angularjsExpression"></button>
```